# Lightbox with ashx extension

Tags: featherlight.js

I am using the LightBox plugin to display images in modal popups. It all works great in the browser with the specified extensions - png|jpg|jpeg|gif|tiff|bmp|svg - in featherlight.min.js.

I am trying to show images with .ashx extension in the modal window. But all I get is garbled text. I can get around this by adding the .ashx extension the above list.

To make upgrades easier in the future, I would like to avoid modifying the above list and add the .ashx extension outside the featherlight.min.js file. I can't find any samples on how to do that.

Is there a way to accomplish this or I just have to modify featherlight.min.js and add the .ashx extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Featherlight supports content filters extension: https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight#content-filters